# Figuring out what's filling up my hard disks

Tags: windows-7, command-line-interface, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization, diskmanagement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are good tools to show disk usage (for Windows)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1687/what-are-good-tools-to-show-disk-usage-for-windows)

In brief, I have a system with several hard disks, and although we install everything on the extra (internal) drives, the primary drive (the one with the OS on it) is almost at max capacity now. This particular setup is a Windows 7 (x64) system which is required for our simulators, and therein lies the problem. On Linux I could just `ls -ltr` to find recently added/modified files, or use `du` to get quick info about disk usage.

Is there a way to do this on Windows via the command line / PS? What's a fast way to figure out what's eating up my space?

---

[image: WinDirStat image]
[WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) - WinDirStat is a disk usage statistics viewer and cleanup tool for Microsoft Windows. It reads the whole directory tree once and then presents it in three useful views:

- The **directory list**, which resembles the tree view of the Windows Explorer but is sorted by file/subtree size,
- The **treemap**, which shows the whole contents of the directory tree straight away,
- The **extension list**, which serves as a legend and shows statistics about the file types.

---

[image: TreeSize Free image]
**[TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/)** - There is both a paid and free version. TreeSize Free can be started from the context menu of a folder or drive and shows you the size of this folder, including its subfolders. You can expand this folder in Explorer-like style and you will see the size of every subfolder. All results can also be drilled down to the file level. Scanning is done in a thread, so you can already see results while TreeSize Free is working. The Explorer context menu is supported within TreeSize, as well as the usual drag & drop operations.

---

[image: Scanner image]
**[Scanner](http://steffengerlach.de/freeware/)** - This tool uses a sunburst chart to display the usage of your hard disk or other media. The chart shows all major files and folders from all directory levels at once.

---

**[Disk Usage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651.aspx)** - command line utility that reports the disk space usage for the directory you specify. By default it recurses directories to show the total size of a directory and its subdirectories.

---

[image: DiskMon image]
**[DiskMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646.aspx)** - an application that logs and displays all hard disk activity on a Windows system. You can also minimize DiskMon to your system tray where it acts as a disk light, presenting a green icon when there is disk-read activity and a red icon when there is disk-write activity.

---

[image: SpaceSniffer image]
**[SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html)** - an application that lets you understand how folders and files are structured on your disks. By using a Treemap visualization layout, you have immediate perception of where big folders and files are placed on your devices.

---

[image: JDiskReport image]
**[JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/)** - an application which enables you to understand how much space the files and directories consume on your disk drives, and it helps you find obsolete files and folders. Requires Java.

---

[image: sequoiaView image]
**[sequoiaView](http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview/about_sequoiaview/)** - a disk browsing tool based on the principle of treemaps, with one unique feature added, namely Cushion Treemaps. The principle is simple: each time a rectangle is subdivided, ridges are added. The result is a pattern of hierarchical cushions that show the structure in the directories and files. The user can set the height of the ridges as well as using lower ridges for deeper nested levels, offering a choice between displaying global information (high level directories) or detailed info such as individual files. The user can also choose between the original cushions and the squarified cushions.

Comment: Also take a look at the related and linked questions in the bar on the right of the duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Why does it have to be from the command line? I like http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/.

Comment: Treesize is great, but if you have 1000 computers to run this on, commandline is the only way to do it easilly

Answer (score 3):

For a free command-line tool, see the [Disk Usage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651) program from SysInternals.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this from the command prompt:

```
> diruse path\to\folder
```

To get the size in Megabytes, you can use '/M'. You can request help as normal using `/?`.